# Editing child records when master is locked in master-detail relationship

Tags: approval-process, sharing, opportunity, record-access-level

When creating a custom master detail relation with oppty object I get to see the sharing setting, which is not available with standard out of box master-detail relation like quote and oppty.

[image]

Does this someway control the record editability when submitting a record for approval? I can create a child on a custom master detail( by setting the radio options above as per BU needs) when the record is locked but not on a standard master detail relationship

Is there something I am missing or is it the Sharing setting option that gives the editability on the custom master detail when the record is submitted for approval?

Please clarify

Comment: This is all about CRUD sharing permissions on the child object based on the Master Object and has nothing to do with changing approval rules. Whatever approval process you have will be whatever you set. If a record is locked for some reason, those locking rules should still apply to the record.

Comment: I should have been more specific on the approval part. why is that I am able to submit a custom child record but not a standard quote record related to an oppty when the oppty is locked?

Comment: Ahhh! That would be because when an oppty is locked, quotes are also locked. The quote is considered part of the Master and not looked at like the child record in the M-D as configured. The assumption is being made that in adding the child record, since you're not doing an update or delete, the operation won't affect the opportunity. Nothing happens to affect an existing quote on the locked oppty. In essence, the quote numbers can't change when you add a new child record (deleting or updating would be another story). Make sense?

Comment: So the quote not being considered as child in the MD is this very specific to oppty-quote relationship (or) does this apply to out of box MD relationships

Comment: No, the quote is still a child of Opp. Everything that `exists` at the time the Opp was locked. That's what gets locked and can't be changed. You can still `insert` child records in the custom M-D relationship, but it doesn't `Update` the `quote` or the `Opp` as it `existed` at the time it was locked. One analogy would be adding a related task; something that's part of the Opp's `activity history`, but doesn't affect the Opp's particulars or the `quote`. The child records you `insert`, don't change the state of the Opp at point when it was locked. Hope that helps clarify.